# Type Promise generic from call to fetch?

Tags: javascript, promise, flowtype, fetch-api

Today I'm facing a little issue with trying to type the Promise from a call to `fetch`.

I have a `callAPI` helper which signature is:

`const apiCall = (url: string, requestOptions: RequestOptions = {}): 
Promise<{}>`

Now, I use it in other helpers, which signature look something like this :

```
const getProps = async (
  // args
): Promise<{}> => {
  const { someProp } = await apiCall(
    // build query with args here 
  );

  return someProp;
};
```

Unfortunately, `flow` complains about that and I haven't managed to type the response here. 
`Cannot call await with apiCall(...) bound to p because property someProp is missing in object type [1] in type argument
R [2].`

```
     /private/tmp/flow/flowlib_65ddbae/core.js
 [2] 583│ declare class Promise<+R> {

     apiCall.js
 [1]  43│ const apiCall = (url: string, requestOptions: RequestOptions = {}): Promise<{}> => {
```

Any idea how to type the response here *without* having to provide all the possible properties of the Response object in the `Response` generic of `apiCall` ? Thanks !

Comment: Isn't there an `Any` type in flow?

Comment: @bergi there is but I try to avoid it as much as I can, otherwise there is no point in using a static type checker really. Plus, too many refinements ..  ;)

Comment: Well but `apiCall` really does not know the type, so it's appropriate there. Then at every call, you'd refine the result type to that which you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making apiCall generic:

```
function apiCall<T>(url: string, requestOptions: RequestOptions = {}): Promise<T> {
  ...
}
```

When you call this function you can pass the expected type to it:

```
const { someProp } = await apiCall<{someProp: type_of_some_prop}>(...);
```

Comment: Thanks  Stefan ! That's exactly what I needed, how could I not think of it.. ah, mornings :)

Comment: No problem @AlexandreGomes, I'm glad I could help. If this answer fixed your issue, please mark it as the solution to your question. Cheers!

Comment: Actually while this should in theory work @stefan-orzu I am experiencing some syntax issues with this. It might well be related to `webpack` flow transform not parsing that syntax as it seems to be fairly new (earlier this month) of a feature :/

Comment: To be honest I don't know very much about flow, my jam is typescript :) But the same principles apply in all typed languages that support generics, so try and see if you could adapt this to the particular version of flow you are using.